# Updating database ODP Oracle.Net Error ORA 01008

Tags: c#, oracle

Hello this question was answered a couple of years ago but its not been active for sometime. When i run the example with my values its giving me a ORA 01008 error but the "therow" values are bounded.

```
     List<string> fldList = new List<string>();

    using (OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};ConnectString=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = x.x.x.xxx)(PORT = xxx)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = xxxx)));UID=xxxx;PWD=xxx;");)
    {
      dbConnection.Open();
      OracleCommand dbCommand2 = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
      dbCommand2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      dbCommand2.CommandText = "update MYTABLE set estatustrama = 2 where rowid = :therow ";
      dbCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("therow", fldList[fldList.Count-1]);

      dbCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] your code does not even compile.

Comment: I'd bet that most people don't know what error ORA 01008 means from memory.  Please post the full error message.

Comment: Also, your code is confusing.  It does not compile.  `OracleConnection` does not have a `Parameters` property to my knowledge.  I presume that is not your actual code.  Please post the actual code that you are having issues with.

Comment: Sorry for the code. It will compile. The ORA 01008 error says : not all variables bound. the problem is therow parameter. The oracle MSDS says to fix it just add : or & on the "dbCommand2.CommandText="  to the parameter and it will bound it but I tried both and still not working

Comment: Why don't you switch to using the [ODP.NET Managed Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) instead of ODBC?

Comment: the problem is the professor wants to use ODBC for the communication.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using ODP.Net. The code you have is using ODBC. For ODBC you cannot use named parameters, only positional. `:therow` should be changed to `?`.

Comment: thanks. I added ? to the row so it looks like ?therow but now is giving me a ORA-01036 error. I i need to post as a different question please let me know. Im new here, sorry

Comment: Is it a requirement to use ODBC? Why don't you use ODP.Net?